# Why differing return values for recursive equation implemented in Scheme and Python?

Tags: python, recursion, lisp

I am trying to implement a basic recursive function in Scheme and I wrote the same function to ensure that I wrote it correctly. The Scheme and Python implementations return the same answers for values from 1 to 7. However, the values begin to diverge after. I am unable to understand why this happening. (This is for homework but this is not the question being asked in the assignment, I just want to understand why the 2 implementations are returning different values)

```
# Function to be implemented 
f(n) = n, if n<4
f(n) = f(n-1) + 2f(n-2) + 3f(n-3) + 4f(n-4), otherwise
```

## Scheme

```
(define (f n)
  (if (< n 4)
      n
      (+ (f (- n 1)) (* 2(f(- n 2))) (* 3(f (- n 3))) (* 4(- n 4)))))

(f 1)
(f 2)
(f 3)
(f 4)
(f 5)
(f 6)
(f 7)
(f 8)
(f 9)
(f 10)

1
2
3
10
26
63
157
377
900
2149
```

## Python

```
def f(n):
    if n<4:
        return n
    else: 
        return f(n-1) + 2*f(n-2) + 3*f(n-3) + 4*f(n-4)


print (f(1))
print (f(2))
print (f(3))
print (f(4))
print (f(5))
print (f(6))
print (f(7))
print (f(8))
print (f(9))
print (f(10))

1
2
3
10
26
63
157
401
1008
2533
```

Answer (score 2):

In your scheme program you have written:

```
(* 4(- n 4))
```

But it should be like so:

```
(* 4(f (- n 4)))
```

Comment: It's generally best to answer typo questions in a comment rather than in a full answer. Such questions are unlikely to benefit future readers, so the system tries to automatically remove them after a week or so. But positive scoring answers interfere with that process.